# WebStorm - Reformat a file vs inline decorator

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm, tslint, reformat

I have set rule prefer-inline-decorator. I want achieve decorator and function name on same line

```
@HostListener('document:keydown.escape', ['$event']) public closeDetail(): void {
```

with WebStorm's Reformat a file (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Alt+L</kbd>). But it reformat it to

```
@HostListener('document:keydown.escape', ['$event'])
public closeDetail(): void {
```

I tried to change Typescript properties in Editor Code Style, but nothing work for me. My settings:

[image]
[image]